# set text gravity center vertical doesn't work in android edit text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-gravity

I am creating some custom `EditText` in android (programmatically with java) and when I wanted to `setGravity` for this `EditText` to set text gravity at the center vertical, it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is my `EditText` and I used `editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);`. But it doesn't set the text to center of the button. Actually `editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);` works correctly.

I don't want to use `editText.setTextAlignment();` because of the version API.

**Edited:**

Can I set Position of text of `EditText` manually? With give it my height and with or give some coordinates.

Comment: please post edittext xml code and java code

Comment: It is to complicated to post the code. But I can promise you that I created the EditText correctly. And I use only java code without any xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

editText.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This is the way you can set gravity programetically

in XML file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

You can use center **Gravity.CENTER** if you want to apply `CENTER_VERTICAL` and  `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` both. same will be for the xml file

Comment: what the result of this ?

Comment: nothing happened. The text is still in the top of the EditText. see my question edit please.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below answer to center the text.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: At first I want something with java code. After I turn your code to java code, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity like below:

```
TextView ta  = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.text_view);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
ta.setLayoutParams(lp);
```